# Why does my Spring handler of Interceptors work wrong when configuring login authentication? feel puzzled

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to configure login authentication on my Spring Boot application. Here is my code:

```
    @Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    if (!(handler instanceof HandlerMethod)) {
        return true;
    }

    HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
    Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod();

    LoginRequired methodAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(LoginRequired.class);
    log.info("{}", method);
    log.info("{}", methodAnnotation);
    if(methodAnnotation==null)return true;

    if(currentUser == null){
        unauth(response);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But now when I request the controller method annotated it outputs:

```
2019-03-15 16:44:33.110  INFO 11624 --- [nio-6789-exec-1] c.ncuhome.tasklist.util.AuthInterceptor  : public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2019-03-15 16:44:33.111  INFO 11624 --- [nio-6789-exec-1] c.ncuhome.tasklist.util.AuthInterceptor  : null
```

My question is Why methodAnnotation is null? And the method seems incorrect.

As a result it's always unable to match the LoginRequired annotation.

the following is the LoginRequired annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LoginRequired {
}
```

Comment: Don't roll your own security, instead I suggest use Spring Security a well tested and proven solution.

Comment: Thanks. I will try later.  But what's I still want to know the problems below.

Comment: Use `handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(LoginRequired.class)` instead of obtaining the method and get annotations from there.

Comment: 2019-03-15 18:29:54.937  INFO 9408 --- [nio-6789-exec-2] c.ncuhome.tasklist.util.AuthInterceptor  : null

Thanks very much. I did as you said, but its outputs is "null". I think the problem seems the handler object since it should be a method inside a controller I've defined. Is there any other way?

Comment: Are you using annotations on your controller that lead to creating a proxy? Like `@Transactional` or the likes?